# While loop program multiple prints and skips conditions?

Tags: python, function, while-loop, conditional-statements, break

Creating a program where I can determine whether I can fit a desired kg of material exactly in a set of 5kg and 1kg containers. The problem is that for some reason the functions always print -1 when it is supposed to do it only if all the conditions fail. Also, for some numbers, it randomly stops working.

The program has 3 inputs:

- the amount of 5kg boxes,
- 1kg boxes and
- the amount of kg material in need of packaging.

It needs to calculate how many boxes are needed if it is even possible. It must use all of the 5kg boxes first if possible. If it can't be done with exact amounts, it needs to print -1.

---

For example.

1. I have

- 2x 5kg boxes,
- 6x 1kg boxes
- 14kg of material.

  At first, I need to use all of the 5kg boxes. Now I have 10kg packed into 2 5kg boxes and 4kg of material left. I have 6 1kg boxes, so I take 4 boxes from there and are left with in total of 6 boxes used in order to package it.

2. If I have

- 2x 5kg boxes,
- 2x 1kg boxes
- 15kg of material,

the program should print out -1, since it isn't possible to pack it.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
s = int(input("Amount of 5kg boxes: "))
v = int(input("Amount of 1kg boxes: "))
k = int(input("Material in kg's: "))

def box(a, b, c):
    kar = 0
    while c>=5 and a>0:
        c = c-5
        a = a-1
        kar = kar + 1
        if c == 0:
            print(kar)
        else:
            if b>=c:
                kar = kar + c
                print(kar)
            else:
                print(-1)
        
        
box(s, v, k)
```

Comment: Please use more descriptive variable names.

Comment: You don't need while loops for this at all.  The number of 5kg boxes you'll use is `min(s, k//5)`.  Then, it takes one `if` to see if what's left will fit in the 1kg boxes you have left.

Comment: Why are you using loops for this? wouldn't just some simple math figure this out for you?

Comment: Just… subtract `number of 5kg boxes * 5` from `material`, then subtract `number of 1kg boxes`, and see if that ends up >= 0…‽

Comment: I meant the `a, b, c` variables.

Comment: Can yo u fit 4kg in a 5kg or should be exact ?

Comment: @azro should be exact.

Answer (score 1):

You only need some math

```
def box(box_5, box_1, amount):
    return (amount - min(box_5, amount // 5) * 5) <= box_1

# same but splitted to get it
def box(box_5, box_1, amount):
    nb_box5_that_can_be_used = min(box_5, amount // 5)
    amount -= nb_box5_that_can_be_used * 5
    return amount <= box_1
```

---

A loop version, so you can get it differently

```
def box(box_5, box_1, amount):
    while amount >= 5 and box_5 > 0:
        amount -= 5
        box_5 -= 1
    return amount <= box_1
```

Comment: not sure what this is doing at all, i feel as if it doesn't use the 1kg boxes at all? i don't get the math logic here either, guess my explanation sucked.

Comment: @RCWZX `box_1` is the amount of box of 1 kg. The thing is that is the amount (after the 5kg removed) is LOWER than the amount of 1kg box, you're right. 4kg and 5 box : OK, so 
 that is why `amount <= box_1`